# Forward Jaeger traces to Datadog

Tags: trace, datadog, jaeger

Is there a way of getting Jaeger traces to Datadog, whether it be through a proxy, scraping traces from Jager and converting them to DD Traces, etc...

We have a vendor provided backend that only supports Jaeger, but the enterprise APM solution is Datadog.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though Datadog's `[OpenTelemetry collector][1]` suggests it will ingest Jaeger traces, there is no documentation to explain how that might work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).